# Why Vue doesn't refresh list using props?

Tags: vue.js

On my App, on `mounted()` method, I call an API, which give to me a JSON with a list of items; than, I update the prop I've set in my target `Homepage` component:

```
Homepage.pages = resJSON.data.pages;
```

Here's the App code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Homepage title="PWA Test"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Homepage from './components/Homepage.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Homepage
  },
  mounted() {
    let endpoint = "http://localhost:5000/api/graphql?query={pages(orderBy:{contentItemId:asc}){contentItemId,createdUtc,author,displayText,description%20}}";

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // check for HTTP failure
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }

        // read and parse the JSON
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        Homepage.pages = res.data.pages;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Here's the `Homepage` component:

```
<template>
  <div id="homepage">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="page in pages" :key="page.description">@{{ page.description }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Homepage',
  props: {
    title: String,
    pages: []
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

But the `ul` doesn't update after receiving the JSON and updating the props `pages`. Where's my error?

Comment: @Flame tried with `this.pages = res.data.pages;`: its the same.

Comment: can you update the question with where you are calling `mounted()`

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara: sure, I've added the whole App code. check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get the `response.json();` in a data property of the App and then pass it down to the `Homepage` component. So your code should you look like this,

App code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    //binding page into data property 
    <Homepage title="PWA Test" :pages="pages"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Homepage from './components/Homepage.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function () {
    return {
      //data propety 
      pages : []
   }
  },
  components: {
    Homepage
  },
  mounted() {
    let endpoint = "http://localhost:5000/api/graphql?query={pages(orderBy:{contentItemId:asc}){contentItemId,createdUtc,author,displayText,description%20}}";

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
        }

        // assign the result to the data property 
        this.page = response.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        Homepage.pages = res.data.pages;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass the props in a template after `this.pages = res.data.pages`?

```
<Homepage :pages="pages" />
```

Comment: Uhm? `pages` is within Homepage component, not App

Comment: In your App component create a `pages` variable in data function like this: `data() { return { pages: [] } }`, then `this.pages = res.data.pages` when you got your data and pass this variable to Homepage component like a mentioned before.

Comment: nothing change. Also, I got a warning: `Property or method "pages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-wood-tqzq8?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some mistakes that you have done in your code, if you want change update prop value then you have to initialized your props values in script.

```
<template>
 <div id="homepage">
   <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
   <ul>
     <li v-for="page in currentPages" :key="page.description">@{{ page.description }} 
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
     name: 'Homepage',
     props: {
       title: String,
       pages: []
     }
     data: function () {
        return {
          currentPages: this.pages
       }
     }

  }
 </script>
```

I hope this will help you to solve your issue- thanks!

Comment: Nothing change adding that data attribute

Comment: Hey can you try computed method to like computed: {
    pages: function () {
      return this.pages;
    }
  }   then call to computed function in template